# Intersection and union of intervals

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Prove that (i) $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in
>  \mathbb{N}}\bigg[1+\frac{1}{n}, 3-\frac{1}{n}\bigg] = (1,3)$ and (ii)
>   $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigg(a-\frac{1}{n},
>  a+\frac{1}{n}\bigg) = \left\{a\right\}$

(i) Let $\displaystyle A =\bigcup_{n \in
 \mathbb{N}}\bigg[1+\frac{1}{n}, 3-\frac{1}{n}\bigg]. $ Let $x \in A$. Then $1+\frac{1}{n} \le x \le  3-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, we have $\min\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) < x < \max\left( 3-\frac{1}{n}\right) \iff 1 < x < 3$, therefore $1<x<3$. Thus $x \in (1,3)$. Hence $A\subseteq (1,3)$. Now suppose $x \not \in A$. Then $x< 1+\frac{1}{n}$ or $x >3-\frac{1}{n}$; in particular, we have $x < \min\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \implies x < 1$ or $x> \max(3-\frac{1}{n}) \implies  x>3$. Thus $x \not \in (1,3)$. Thus $A = (1,3)$.

(ii) Let $\displaystyle A =\bigcap_{n \in
 \mathbb{N}}\bigg(a-\frac{1}{n}, a+\frac{1}{n}\bigg). $ Let $x \in A$. Then $a-\frac{1}{n}< x < a+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular we have $\max\left(a-\frac{1}{n}\right)< x < \min\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right) \iff a < x < a$. Thus $x \not\in \left\{a\right\}$. But $x \in \left\{a\right\}  \Rightarrow x \in A$.

And I give up. So what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: on the first line of your (i) proof "all $n$" should be "some $n$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{a-1/n:n\in N\}$ has no largest member (no max).The set $\{a+1/n:n\in N\}$ has no least member (no min).If $ x\ne a$ then $x>a+1/n$ or $x<a-1/n$ for some $n\in N$ so $x$ cannot belong to every $(a-1/n,a+1/n).$

Be careful to distinguish between max and lub, also between min and glb.